# Freeze on losing network connection

Tags: networking, mount, nfs

When I mount a server file system that is located in a local network over nfs on my laptop, the processes interacting with the filesystem freeze / hang up whenever the network connection is lost. The file explorer (Dolphin) window freezes, and through the terminal I cannot display the contents of the directory that contains the mount point. Trying to `sudo umount` the folder won't work.

In my case, I use `sudo mount -t nfs 192.168.1.100:/elrudi /home/elrudi/nas`. I can still `cd` to any location, but when I try to `ls` the contents of `/home/elrudi`, the terminal window hangs. All I can do is force-close the affected windows. When opening a new dolphin/terminal window, the problem persists.

Some observations:

- If the network connection gets restored, the problem goes away - most of the times. Curiously, dolphin seems to need a little kick to unfreeze, which can be administered by `ls`ing `/home/elrudi` in a terminal.
- If the network connection cannot be restored, however, such as when it is out of reach, there is nothing that can be done (that I know of). Even rebooting the system is not an option, as it hangs at the 'final' screen ('ubuntu' with process progress dots that light up one after the other).

I'd like to know if there is a way to make a more robust mount, or if there is something I can do to make the system responsive again.

Thanks!

Comment: Also, when I try to shut down the system, it hangs at the final screen (the 'ubuntu' name with 5 dots indicating an active process)

Comment: A problem also in Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Be sure to let me know if more information is needed for diagnostics, or if there is another way of mounting the drive that does not freeze the system.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the answers in this former post:

[How to unmount NFS when server is gone?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/292043/how-to-unmount-nfs-when-server-is-gone)

I usually do not use static mounts to NFS shares, but rather install autofs and use softlinks like (in your case)

```
ln -s /net/192.168.1.100/elrudi /home/elrudi/nas
```

This will mount the share only when used, and umount after a while.

Comment: Unfortunately, my laptop is currently in repair, so I cannot verify your answer, but as the bounty will otherwise expire and not benefit anyone, I'll award it to you. Thanks for the answer! I'll definitely look into it once I have my equipment back

Comment: Thank You. It was not for the bounty, just try to help. When you got your laptop back, don't hesitate to ask if you need more help.